# Secondary lookup columns for external content types not displaying data in list after refreshing from primary

Tags: lookup-column, external-content-type, external-list, external-data-column, crawl-external-content

I have created a SharePoint list that has a lookup column to an external list. I also have instructed SharePoint to display several secondary columns that are related to that primary external lookup column in my list as well.

The problem is that after I programmatically add a new `SPListItem` to my list and set the `SPLookupValue` for the primary lookup field (which works fine) when I go to the list view in my SharePoint portal I see the value in the primary field but when I click the green **refresh data from external list** icon in the column header to load the data from the external list into the secondary fields I get the following message.

> Refresh successful.
>
> 0 item(s) were refreshed.
>
> 0 item(s) could not be refreshed. Contact your system Administrator.

In addition, when I try to edit the `SPListItem` the value that displays in the primary external lookup column (which should be a valid value) I am greeting with the message displayed below the textbox that reads:

> "No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options. You can also use Select button to choose External Data."

When I click on the icon to select the external data, I get the pop-up window/dialog that allows me to select items from the external list. All of the data displays properly. There are no errors. But when I actually select one of the rows and click "**OK**" I get the same red error message saying that ***"No exact match was found..."***.

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with my External Content Type, BDC Model, Specific Finder method that is responsible for retrieving the data for a specific entity result but I'm just not sure how to identify exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I figured out the problem.

I had created Identifiers for ALL of my entity's properties instead of just creating identifiers for only the properties that makes the specific entity unique! I had created identifiers for properties that had null values and others that were of type DateTime that do not at all uniquely identify the entity. As a result, when trying to perform a refresh on the external list data, it was trying to retrieve the external data for each of the individual list items with the assumption that every single column/field in the external list was part of the unique identifier for a particular list item. Obviously that prevented the data from refreshing correctly.

Comment: Mark your question as answered:)